# Android Inter Process Communication through Binder

Tags: android, performance

How does android provide faster IPC via Binder than any normal IPC mechanisms like Sockets or Pipes etc?

Comment: it deesn't, sockets and pipes are faster

Comment: then why they wrote this "Base interface for a remotable object, the core part of a lightweight remote procedure call mechanism designed for high performance when performing in-process and cross-process calls. " in IBinder interface documentation ? Do they use sockets and pipes internally ?

Comment: it doesn't mention that it is faster then sockets and pipes but i have no idea how it is implemented, more here: http://elinux.org/Android_Binder and https://www.nds.rub.de/media/attachments/files/2011/10/main.pdf

Comment: for some reference code see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656775/rapid-ipc-with-messengers-or-aidl)