# ObjectInputStream is not able to recognize my Object Data format

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, objectinputstream

I am getting `EOFException` from the following code:

```
if (!(in.read() == -1))
{
    CANDataInfo canData = (CANDataInfo) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(canData.toString());
    bw.write(canData.toString());
}
else
{
    System.out.println("in.read() == -1 "+in.readObject());
    jLab0x28.setText("No more bytes to read ");
}
```

I am doing an Socket programming where server is sending continuos data to client at some interval. The Data whichis passed from server to client in via socket is of type CANDataInfo object which i have developed. At client side while i am printing the data i am getting exception. Since object's read is always -1 i am not able to log the data on some file.

**Server Side Code:**

```
private ServerSocket server = null;
private Socket client = null;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
public static final String TAG = "APP1";

private void structureData(CANDataInfo canDataInfo)
{
    try 
    { 
        if(server == null) 
        {   
            server = new ServerSocket(38301);
            server.setSoTimeout(0);
        }
        client = server.accept();
        Log.e("Server ", ""+client.isConnected());
        Log.e("Data ", ""+canDataInfo.toString());

        if(!client.isConnected())
        {   
            Log.e("Server ", "client.isConnected() "+client.isConnected());
            server.close();
        }

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(canDataInfo);

        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(CANManagerSetUp.TAG, "" + ex);
    }
}
```

**Client Side Code** **{Not a clean solution, Refer Answer from EJP}**

```
   package com.cnh.socket.client;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import cantest.setup.CANDataInfo;


public class ThreadListener
{   
    Socket client = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ListenFor0X28 runnableListenFor0X28 = null;
    boolean continueMe;


    public class ListenFor0X28 implements Runnable 
    {   
        JLabel jLab0x28; 

        public ListenFor0X28(){}

        public ListenFor0X28(boolean stop, JLabel jLab0x28) 
        {
            continueMe = stop;
            this.jLab0x28 = jLab0x28;
        }

        public void run() 
        {   

            while(continueMe)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = new Socket("localhost", 38301);
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                    if(client.isConnected())
                    {   
                        jLab0x28.setText("Connected to Server");
                        appendFile(continueMe, jLab0x28, client);

                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Client is trying to connect");
                        jLab0x28.setText("Client is trying to connect");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {   
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println("Before Append "+ex.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedWriter file = getFile("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt");
    private void appendFile(boolean continueMe, JLabel jLab0x28, Socket client)
    {   
        try
        {   
            if(!client.isClosed())
            {   
                try
                {   
                    CANDataInfo canData = (CANDataInfo) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(canData.toString());
                    file.write(canData.toString());
                    file.flush();

                }
                catch (EOFException exp)
                {   
                    continueMe = true;
                    System.out.println("A Stream has finished "+exp.toString()+"\n");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) 
                {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(exp.toString());
                    continueMe = false;
                }
            }

            if(!continueMe)
            {
                file.close();
                client.close();
                in.close();
                jLab0x28.setText("Socket is closed "+client.isClosed());
            }

        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception "+exp.toString());
            jLab0x28.setText(exp.getMessage());
            continueMe = false;
        }
    }

    public BufferedWriter getFile(String path) 
    {
        try 
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (!file.exists()) 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            return new BufferedWriter(fw);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exception Stack: {Before Resolving}

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.cnh.socket.client.ThreadListener.appendFile(ThreadListener.java:73)
    at com.cnh.socket.client.ThreadListener.access$0(ThreadListener.java:65)
    at com.cnh.socket.client.ThreadListener$ListenFor0X28.run(ThreadListener.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Data received in unknown format java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: Print your stacktrace with `classNot.printStackTrace()` - or at least `classNot.toString()`. Your current message is incomplete as it doesn't show which exception was thrown.

Comment: My Bad, i have updated question. Please check. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Why you would call an unknown exception `classNot` is another mystery, as is why you would call `getLocalizedMessage()` only to throw the result away.

Comment: Don't remove the original code that constituted the problem that is answered here. Otherwise the question is meaningless to future readers, and its retention here is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the pointless and erroneous `read()` call, which is getting your object streams out of sync.

While you're at it, you can also remove all the redundant calls to `isConnected()`. They aren't doing anything. You seem to have a mania for calling extra methods which mostly don't do anything, or which try to predict the future. Try to taper off.

**EDIT** As requested I am critiquing not only your client but your server code.

Server:

```
private void structureData(CANDataInfo canDataInfo)
{
    try 
    { 
        if(server == null)
```

The `ServerSocket` should have been created and configured in the constructor.

```
        {   
            server = new ServerSocket(38301);
            server.setSoTimeout(0);
```

Zero is the default. Don't assert defaults. Remove.

```
        }
        client = server.accept();
        Log.e("Server ", ""+client.isConnected());
```

Logging `isConnected()` is redundant. Remove. This will always print `true`. The socket *is* connected. You just accepted it. If you want to log something useful, log the client socket's remote address.

```
        Log.e("Data ", ""+canDataInfo.toString());
```

How can there be any data when you haven't read any yet? If this is invariant server-side data, why log it on every accept?

```
        if(!client.isConnected())
        {   
            Log.e("Server ", "client.isConnected() "+client.isConnected());
            server.close();
        }
```

This test can never pass, and the code block can never be entered, and if by some miracle it was entered, closing the server socket is a ridiculous response. Remove all this.

```
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(canDataInfo);

        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
```

Don't catch `Exception`. Catch `IOException`.

```
    {
        Log.e(CANManagerSetUp.TAG, "" + ex);
```

You should log the exception class, its message, and the stack trace. `""+ex` does not accomplish that.

```
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class ThreadListener
{   
    Socket client = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ListenFor0X28 runnableListenFor0X28 = null;
    boolean continueMe;


    public class ListenFor0X28 implements Runnable 
    {   
        JLabel jLab0x28; 

        public ListenFor0X28(){}

        public ListenFor0X28(boolean stop, JLabel jLab0x28) 
        {
            continueMe = stop;
            this.jLab0x28 = jLab0x28;
        }

        public void run() 
        {   

            while(continueMe)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = new Socket("localhost", 38301);
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                    if(client.isConnected())
```

The client *is* connected. You just connected it, when you constructed the `Socket`. And if by some miracle it wasn't connected, calling `getInputStream()` would already have failed with a `SocketException`. Remove this test. In general there is far too much testing of things that can't be true or can't be false in your code.

```
                    {   
                        jLab0x28.setText("Connected to Server");
                        appendFile(continueMe, jLab0x28, client);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Client is trying to connect");
                        jLab0x28.setText("Client is trying to connect");
                    }
                }
```

The `else` block is unreachable, and the log message `'Client is trying to connect'` is incorrect. Remove the entire block and the `else`.

```
                catch(Exception ex)
```

See above. Don't catch `Exception`. Catch the exceptions the compiler tells you to catch: in this case `IOException` and the DNS-related ones.

```
                {   
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println("Before Append "+ex.toString());
```

See above about how to log exceptions.

```
                }
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedWriter file = getFile("C:\\ISSUE124_Resolved.txt");

    private void appendFile(boolean continueMe, JLabel jLab0x28, Socket client)
    {   
        try
        {   
            if(!client.isClosed())
            {   
                try
                {   
                    CANDataInfo canData = (CANDataInfo) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(canData.toString());
                    file.write(canData.toString());
                    file.flush();
                }
                catch (EOFException exp)
                {   
                    continueMe = true;
                    System.out.println("A Stream has finished "+exp.toString()+"\n");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) 
                {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(exp.toString());
                    continueMe = false;
                }
            }

            if(!continueMe)
            {
                file.close();
                client.close();
                in.close();
```

You don't need to close both the input stream and the socket. Either will do. General practice is to close the outermost writer/output stream if there is one, otherwise the input stream.

```
                jLab0x28.setText("Socket is closed "+client.isClosed());
            }

        }
        catch(IOException exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception "+exp.toString());
            jLab0x28.setText(exp.getMessage());
            continueMe = false;
        }
    }

    public BufferedWriter getFile(String path) 
    {
        try 
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (!file.exists()) 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
```

Here you are (1) testing for file existence and (2) creating a new file.

```
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Here the operating system will create a new file regardless of what you did above. The `exists()/createNewFile()` part is therefore a complete waste of time: two system calls that accomplish precisely nothing. Remove them.

```
            return new BufferedWriter(fw);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

Poor practice. You should let this method throw `IOException` and not catch it internally, or return `null`. At present, if this method fails, you will get an instrutable `NullPointerException` when you go to use its return value.

```
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information, i have done changes collaborating your comments and this potential answer. I am ending up with EOF Exception. I know EOFException when input stream has reached the end but if i do if (!(in.read() == -1)) i am getting nothing and even my server on Android Display is not sending any data and just keeps on stacking it.

Comment: when you will be refering this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935354/sending-continuos-data-from-service-to-activity-at-really-very-high-speed you will understand what i were actually trying to perform. and why i had to do put all in a while loop. Anyway, please check my code of client side and if possible provide me with feedback to clean way. i will accept your answer

Comment: @PawankumarDubey You seem to have already learned enough from my answer to incorporate all of it in your code, without me having to repeat it for you, and my answer already contains an explanation. As requested I have critiqued your code. I should not have to read another question to understand what you are trying to perform here. I haven't said anything about `while` loops, and I don't understand why you mention it.

Answer (score 2):

In the client

```
if (!(in.read() == -1))
{
    CANDataInfo canData = (CANDataInfo) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(canData.toString());
    bw.write(canData.toString());
}
```

The first line reads one byte from the input stream.  This is actually the first byte of the object that was written by the server.  Thus the stream is no longer aligned correctly so the following `readObject()` fails.

Comment: I have just tried sending string object from Server like out.writeObject(canDataInfo.toString); and on client data is getting printed in else condition i.e.  when (in.read() == -1) . How can i relate this with your answer, please find updated question for exact exception

Comment: @PawankumarDubey I don't know why you're passing a `toString()` result to a method than can accept any Serializable object, but unless you sent a byte ahead of it the code you posted will fail.

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you please go thru entire Client side source code once ?