# Android: Communication between two Services of two separate APKs

Tags: android, service, ipc, messaging, aidl

**Situation:**

I have an Android **System Application** (persistent) with a `Service` that is supposed to run all the time. (Let's call it Service A)

Then there is another Application (not a System Application; normal App) that also has a `Service`. But this `Service` might run or might not run since the Android OS will kill it if it needs resources. (Let's call it Service B)

In short: We have two Applications (hence 2 APKs) that can be signed with the same certificate. (So they could run in the same process right?)

**What I try to accomplish**

The Service A listens to events. When it receives an event then I want the Service A to call the normal App (Service B) which should give a response back to Service A.

**Approaches to let the two Services communicate**

I could let them communicate using:

- Binding (using an AIDL)
- Messaging (but not optimal since passing complex objects is a must)

**Problems**

- Which way to communicate is "the best" one for the described case?
- What happens when Service A wants to delegate/send a message to Service B and Service B is not running? It must get a response from Service B. Should I always start Service B if it is not running when Service A wants to call it?

Thank you!

Comment: if you want it fast and complex data to be passed see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33688843/2252830)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which way to communicate is "the best" one for the described case?

You only cite two options, since "Aidl" and "Binding" are the same thing. You use AIDL to describe and implement the client-side proxy and the server-side stub for cross-process service binding.

Given that you want call-and-response, binding is probably a better choice. Note, though, that there is no IPC approach that supports "complex objects" very well, outside of using `Parcelable`, `Serializable`, or converting the object graph into JSON or something.

> What happens when Service A wants to delegate/send a message to Service B and Service B is not running?

When you call `startService()` or `bindService()`, Android forks a process for App B and creates an instance of the service (invoking its `onCreate()`) method. At that point, the behavior is the same as if the process and service had already been running.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer - I appreciate it! So you would bind the Service and use an AIDL to describe the API?

Comment: @sjkm: Yes. If you want a synchronous response, like a regular method call, have your AIDL interface define a return value on the method. If you want an asynchronous response, define AIDL both for Service B and for a callback object that will be passed from A. Then, pass an instance of the callback object in the AIDL-defined method, and B can use that to call a method on A's callback to provide the asynchronous results. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Callback) for an example of the callback approach.

Comment: Thank you! That looks great. I will have a deeper look at it tomorrow. Have a nice evening.

Comment: I'd like to ask you a last question: A messenger (without AIDL) would only work for the same application (but remote processes), right?

Comment: @sjkm: You could use that for the callback, as opposed to a custom AIDL-defined callback. I don't see what it gains you.

Answer (score 0):

If application containing Service A is a System Application then how these two apps can be signed with the same certificate ?

Do you have the access to platform certificate?

Anyways aidl will be a good option since you want a response from service B.

Comment: You do not need to sign an App with the platform certificate in order for it to be a System Application. It just has to be installed in the "/system/app" / "system/priv-app" folder...